# How to make a parallel lines

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have this:

```
        // mDY = current Y-axis position
        // first point (X1, Y1), second point (X2,Y2);
        if (Y1 > mDY)
            mDY1 = Y1 - Math.abs(Y1 - mDY);
        else if (Y1 < mDY)
            mDY1 = Y1 + Math.abs(Y1 - mDY);

        if (Y2 > mDY)
            mDY2 = Y2 - Math.abs(Y2 - mDY);
        else if (Y2 < mDY)
            mDY2 = Y2 + Math.abs(Y2 - mDY);


                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(X1,Y1);
                ctx.lineTo(X2,Y2);            
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(X1, mDY1);
                ctx.lineTo(X2, mDY2);
                ctx.stroke();
```

What I want is to have this result:

Basically they are always parallel like the parallel channel.

Comment: I'd remove `else mDYn = 0`

Comment: @JanTuroň already updated my question

Comment: It seems that you ommited some important code to post here. How about `mDY1 = Y1+10; mDY2 = Y2+10` instead of your `if - else if` blocks?

Comment: @JanTuroň It will be hardcoded which we dont want

Comment: because it can be drag to different position

Comment: Then edit your question and explain the meaning of the symbols and show how `mDY` is calculated.

Comment: Please clarify your question so we know clearly the input and the expected output.

Comment: @newuser1 now your problem has an answer, see below. BTW you haven't accepted any answer to your questions yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of absolute value, you can shorten this snippet

```
if (Y1 > mDY)
    mDY1 = Y1 - Math.abs(Y1 - mDY);
else if (Y1 < mDY)
    mDY1 = Y1 + Math.abs(Y1 - mDY);
```

to this

```
mDY1 = Y1 - (Y1 - mDY)
```

which is

```
mDY1 = mDY
// and mDY2 = mDY, which is horizontal line
```

What you want is

```
mDY1 = Y1 - mDY;
mDY2 = Y2 - mDY;
```